# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to install paperclip, image magick and mimemagic.

I successfully installed imagemagic.

Upon installing paperclip, it loops the error to the ff:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    mimemagic (= 0.3.3)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2.4) was resolved to 5.2.4, which depends on
      activestorage (= 5.2.4) was resolved to 5.2.4, which depends on
        marcel (~> 0.3.1) was resolved to 0.3.3, which depends on
          mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)

    paperclip (~> 4.3, >= 4.3.6) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Then if I run `bundle update`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    mimemagic (~> 0.3.1)

    paperclip (~> 4.3, >= 4.3.6) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
```

I am using Ubuntu (linux). Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# additional gems
gem 'faker', '~> 2.8', '>= 2.8.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.0.5'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.3.1'
```

Here's my Gemfile.lock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4)
      activejob (= 5.2.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
    activerecord (5.2.4)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    archive-zip (0.12.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.7.3)
      execjs
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap (4.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)
      popper_js (>= 1.14.3, < 2)
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    capybara (3.29.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.1)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faker (2.8.1)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 1.8)
    ffi (1.11.3)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.1)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    popper_js (1.14.5)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    puma (3.12.2)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.4)
      actioncable (= 5.2.4)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4)
      activejob (= 5.2.4)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4)
      activestorage (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.1)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bootstrap (~> 4.4, >= 4.4.1)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  faker (~> 2.8, >= 2.8.1)
  font-awesome-rails (~> 4.7, >= 4.7.0.5)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  kaminari (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.4)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

I am pretty sure that the imagemagick is installed cause when i run `magick -version` it show the version of the app. I am really thinking how to solve this. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: "Any idea how to solve this problem?" get rid of paperclip and choose another library (shrine? carrierwave? rails built-in activestorage?). It's no longer maintained anyway.

Comment: Paperclip is currently at version 6, any reason to use version 4? Note they don't recommend to use it for new projects https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is not able to resolve the dependencies because 'mimemagic' gem's version is a conflict between rails and paperclip gems.

As you can see in the logs, rails v5 requires mimemagic to be in v0.3.2 and paperclip v4 requires mimemagic to be in v0.3.0.

To solve this case take either of the two approaches below:

1. upgrade paperclip to higher version which supports mimemagic v0.3.2
2. downgrade the rails version to support mimemagic v0.3.0

Also explicitly you specified in your Gemfile that the mimemagic version to be ~> 0.3.1 which doesn't satisfy either rails or paperclip. As long as it is not intentional for any other purpose, it can be changed/removed accordingly.